# Redirecionar página JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Tenho um bean SessionScoped que utilizo para navegar dados da página 1 para a página 2. A página 1 é acessada pelo menu, já a página 2 é acessada por um botão dentro da página 1, onde são carregados alguns dados baseados em filtros desta primeira página. Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Caso o usuário digite a url dessa página 2 na mão, como posso redirecionar ela para a primeira página?

Comment: O que voce quer é proibir o acesso a URL's de determinados usuários? Por exemplo, usuário x não tem permissão pra acessar pagina y. Caso ele tente acessar a página y na mão ele é redirecionado pra página de login?

Comment: Não determinados usuários, mas sim todos. Caso o usuário tente entrar na página 2 manualmente, redirecionar para a página 1. Até porque se ele entrar direto na página 2 vai dar pau, pois tem dados que são pegos da página 1.

Comment: Pensei em algo agora mas não sei se funciona, voce pode criar um phaseListener que verifica se os dados estão nulos, se eles estiverem nulos a pagina não poderá ser acessada

Answer (score 0):

Chame um método do seu Bean antes de inicializar a página 2, verifique se o usuário preencheu os dados necessários na página 1, se não redirecione a página 1.

Utilizando as tags abaixo, a página 2 não chega a ser recarregada:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{pagina2Bean.inicializar()}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

**Obs.:** tag (f) é da biblioteca Core do JSF.

Ou faça com JavaScript:

```
window.onload = new function(){
  #{pagina2Bean.inicilizar()}
}
```

Comment: Eu sou a favor do JS para funções básicas como essa, porém, a pergunta foi em JSF!